# Groovy: get value from xml

Tags: xml, groovy

I am new in groovy and I want to get value from XML. This is my XML
and my value what I want is `name="name_of_something"`.

Could somebody help me with this problem ?

```xml
<data>
  <object bo="45345345" name="name_of_something" uniqueid="name_some">
    <property name="Id" propid="423423423">"something"></property>
  </object>
</data>
```

I want the result to be: `<Name>Name="name_of_something"</Name>`

Answer (score 1):

```
import groovy.xml.*
def xmlString = '''<data>
  <object bo="45345345" name="name_of_something" uniqueid="name_some">
    <property name="Id" propid="423423423">"something"</property>
  </object>
</data>'''
new MarkupBuilder().Name("Name=\"${new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlString).object.@name}\"")
```

Produces:

```
<Name>Name="name_of_something"</Name>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option without the XML-parsing mumbo-jumbo is to use simple regex:

```
String txt = '''<data>
<object bo="45345345" name="name_of_something" uniqueid="name_some">
<property name="Id" propid="423423423">"something"</property>
</object>
</data>'''

String value = ( txt =~ /<object [^<>\/]*name="(\w+)"[^<>\/]*>/ ).findResult{ _, val -> val }

assert value == 'name_of_something'
```